# Declare new object with type T

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to make a binary search tree and the class looks like this:

```
public class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    
    T data;
    Node<T> left
    Node<T> right;
    int height;
    
    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
        this.height = 0;
    }
    
}
```

My client program where I'm declaring the object looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Node<T> a = new Node<T>(8);
    
}
```

Then the error comes up as The constructor `Node<T>(T)` refers to the missing type T. I want to know how to declare the T data as an int type of 8. How do I do that without changing the Node class?

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
Node<Integer> a = new Node<>(8);
```

Further read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Answer (score 1):

after the generic is defined you need especific objects

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Node<Integer> a = new Node<Integer>(8);
    //or
    Node<String> s = new Node<String>("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

T as generic class type, int Primitive type, that's why there is a classe called Integer witch is a wrapper of int

```
Node<Integer> a = new Node<>(8);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `T` with a type like `Integer`:

```java
Node<Integer> a = new Node<>(8);
```

Note that you cannot use `int` as only object/reference types are allowed as generic. Primitive types cannot be used.